# How to write concise compare methods in Java?

Tags: java, comparator

I am writing a compararator to sort log lines:

Code:

```
public static final Comparator<String> HTMLcomparator = new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String line1, String line2)
        {
            HTMLLogLine htmlLogLine1 = new HTMLLogLine(line1);
            HTMLLogLine htmlLogLine2 = new HTMLLogLine(line2);
            int fullCompare = 0;

            String requestId1 = htmlLogLine1.getRequestId();
            String requestId2 = htmlLogLine2.getRequestId();

            if(requestId1 != null && requestId2 != null)
            {
                fullCompare = requestId1.compareTo(requestId2);
            }
            else if(requestId1 == null && requestId2 != null)
            {
                fullCompare = -1;
            }
            else if(requestId1 != null)
            {
                fullCompare = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fullCompare = 0;
            }

            if(fullCompare == 0)
            {
                String security1 = htmlLogLine1.getSecurity();
                String security2 = htmlLogLine2.getSecurity();
                if(security1 != null && security2 != null)
                {
                    fullCompare = security1.compareTo(security2);
                }
                else if(security1 == null && security2 != null)
                {
                    fullCompare = -1;
                }
                else if(security1 != null && security2 == null)
                {
                    fullCompare = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fullCompare = 0;
                }
            }

            if(fullCompare == 0)
            {
                String scenario1 = htmlLogLine1.getScenario();
                String scenario2 = htmlLogLine2.getScenario();

                if(scenario1 != null && scenario2 != null)
                {
                    fullCompare = scenario1.compareTo(scenario2);
                }
                else if(scenario1 == null && scenario2 != null)
                {
                    fullCompare = -1;
                }
                else if(scenario1 != null)
                {
                    fullCompare = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fullCompare = 0;
                }
            }

            if(fullCompare == 0)
            {

                Optional<Instant> timestamp1 = htmlLogLine1.getTimestamp();
                Optional<Instant> timestamp2 = htmlLogLine2.getTimestamp();

                if(timestamp1.isPresent() && timestamp2.isPresent())
                {
                    fullCompare = timestamp1.get().compareTo(timestamp2.get());
                }
                else if(!timestamp1.isPresent() && timestamp2.isPresent())
                {
                    fullCompare = -1;
                }
                else if(timestamp1.isPresent() && !timestamp2.isPresent())
                {
                    fullCompare = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fullCompare = 0;
                }

            }
            return fullCompare;
        }
    };
```

The code seems very naive and has a lot of duplication. Any ideas how to make it concise?

Previous to this code, I had written the following code in compare method:

```
Comparator<HTMLLogLine > fullComparator = Comparator.comparing(HTMLLogLine ::getRequestId)
                                                                   .thenComparing(HTMLLogLine ::getSecurity)
                                                                   .thenComparing(HTMLLogLine ::getScenario);


                    fullCompare = fullComparator.compare(logLine1, logLine2);
```

However,to my surprise the code threw exception: Compare method does not follow the contract!

How can I make this comparator concise yet make it work?

Comment: your comparison seems to run in four stages. You could write the comparisons by stages in separate methods (maybe static utility methods) and then chain them. This would simplify the actual compare method. You could then chain the calls with [`Comparator.comparing(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) and [`Comparator.thenComparing(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: If you got that exception, one or more of your line methods are probably producing inconsistent results. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, don't [double post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193296/compares-two-log-lines).